# Magento - Mageworx Extended Orders - rearrange columns

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have more or less inherited a Magento site, which seems to `be using the Mageworx Extended Orders extension for the order grid in the admin area`.

Client would like the columns to be rearranged, eg, move Email over beside Voucher. In the System Config you can select columns but there doesn't seem to be any way of ordering them. I have searched through the code and tried editing `code\local\MageWorx\Adminhtml\Block\Orderspro\Sales\Order\Grid.php` to no avail.

I also looked in the database but `couldn't find a table which might have the columns selected so that I could order them.`

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, there was no code really to put in at that stage. As it happens it was that file, MageWorx\Adminhtml\Block\Orderspro\Sales\Order\Grid.php, that I needed to edit. I took out the loop and just commented out the fields I didn't want showing and put the rest in the required order.

Answer (score 0):

As it happens it was that file, MageWorx\Adminhtml\Block\Orderspro\Sales\Order\Grid.php, that I needed to edit. I took out the loop and just commented out the fields I didn't want showing and put the rest in the required order

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the file: app/code/local/MageWorx/OrdersPro/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php in the _prepareColumns() method.

At the moment changing columns order is quite a challenge and can be done only this way:

```
$listColumns = $helper->getGridColumns();

$listColumnsChanged = $listColumns; // create a copy of $listColumns

$listColumnsChanged[0] = $listColumns[3]; 
$listColumnsChanged[3] = $listColumns[0]; // interchange the columns that have id 3 and 0

var_dump($listColumns); // var_dump will let you learn ID of the column you need 
foreach ($listColumnsChanged as $column) { // change foreach for getting to $listColumnsChanged
```